# How to symbolize groups separately in a graph (R)

Tags: r, plot

I have a small data set consisting of two columns of data and a column designating which of the two sites the data was taken at.  I have used `xyplot` to sort by groups, but I can't figure out how to alter the symbology of each group separately.  I also need to add a regression line, and can only figure out how to do that in `plot`.  What graphics package can give me these features in the same graph?

I have looked into different graphics packages to find one in which I can do everything I need, but I am new to R and am not having much luck.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2 is your go-to.

Try this:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
one=c("A","B","A","B")
two=c(1,2,3,4)
three=c(5,7,8,20)
df<-data.frame(one,two,three)
ggplot(df,aes(x=two,y=three,col=one))+geom_line()
```